# Auth user message when user is logged in Web2py

Tags: web2py

I am doing a project where I am not using the default `layout.html`. In this case, how can I display the "Welcome User" message when the user is logged in?

I looked through everything but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default `layout.html`, that is handled via `auth.navbar()`, which takes several options. Alternatively, you can just add the appropriate custom markup to your own template -- something like:

```
{{='Welcome %s' % auth.user.first_name if auth.user else ''}}
```